How to erase text from image using object remover with e.g. stable diffusion
I am working on a personal project. I want to erase the text from an image and reconstruct the background. This is from what I understand an object removal and inpainting job which a model like stable diffusion should be able to do.
So I have already extracted a mask with the relevant text boxes masked in white rectangles and use an empty prompt with stable diffusion. However, the results are never as good as what I can do on for example a random website: https://snapedit.app/remove-object#google_vignette
Note I want to do this in Python. So my main question is, am I forgetting something? Am I using the wrong model? Or the wrong prompt? Because it seems to me that these websites run very fast so I don't suspect that the model goes over iterations but rather does it in one go.
I provide you with a sample image. I want to remove 'Let Kids experience the wonder of flight' and 'Soars up to 200 ft'. Note I have the masks. It's just the model and/or the prompts that I use might be wrong. I work on a macbook pro m3. The goal is to remove the text and reconstruct the sky background. The website  https://snapedit.app/remove-object#google_vignette does it well so I think I should be able to do it as well.
Example Image

I have found the solution: In short: Use OCR to have the bounded boxes. Give those bounded boxes as the masks and do not give any prompt. I used the Simplelama package. Small tip: I added some curvature to the bounded boxes as I notice the final results were better.
